# RNAWSCognitoModule tries to override versioned host RNAWSCognitoModule in MainApplication

Tags: react-native, amazon-cognito, expo, aws-amplify, aws-pinpoint

I'm getting an error in `react-native` (ExpoKit) project after adding `aws push notification`, I don't have duplicates in `MainApplication`. How is possible to fix this problem?

```
  public List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
    return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
            new RNAWSCognitoPackage(),
            new RNPushNotificationPackage(),
            new WheelPickerPackage()
    );
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did `react-native unlink amazon-cognito-identity-js` and problem disappeared